# Changing Core Data when app starts

Tags: ios, swift, networking, xml-parsing

I am developing an iOS app which downloads xml data that are valid for 4 hours. I want to check validity and, if needed, update this data when my app starts.

I am using this xml parser to load data http://www.theappguruz.com/blog/xml-parsing-using-nsxmlparse-swift

Right now I am calling `beginParse()` and parsing data in `AppDelegate.swift` in `function didiFinishLaunchingWithOptions`. Is this the correct place to perform this background task?

In tutorial which I posted the guy does it in view controller but I want to use this parser to update coredata and I need it to run in background after app launches.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The professional way to do this would be have a function (or even a full class), to manage this download/parse data and **asynchronously** save in your core data, after that, you can inform the view that you have new content to load (or if there was an error or something).

About where to call the function, it depends...

If you should only show to the user the most updated information (like locking the screen whit a "loading..." or something like it), put the call in the first view controller, just because would be simpler to just call an completion handler to unlock and load the data.

But, if you can load the "old" information, just to be faster and refresh when the new content is available, i think that you can call in the appDelegate with no problem.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Right now I have created totaly new class to parse and save xml. However I must check docs to determine whether contentsOfUrl(NSURL) is asynchronous or not. I can use older data so I will call it in appDelegate

Comment: Just in case, you can check this link, it shows how to make an async request. http://www.kaleidosblog.com/swift-uitableview-load-data-from-json

Comment: thanks but it uses NSURLConnection which is deprecated since iOS 9. I will probabl use NSURLSession introduced in iOS 7. My deployment target is iOS 7 so it will do